# Toggler Button and the navbar Header is not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar header,the Brand Name and a navbar toggler button done in bootstrap but the problem I'm facing not is,it is not inline. I tried all the possibilities but couldn't find a solution.

here is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0">Navbar</h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: it doesn't work,I have already tried @DarrenSweeney

Comment: What version of BS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the latest Bootstrap Alpha 6 which is not yet stable. You'd need to use `navbar-toggler-right`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0">Navbar</h1>
</nav>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/RzbJNIMm1b